# Accessing a Queue from standalone code

Tags: java, queue, websphere, jndi, rad

I have a Queue configured in the Rational Application Developer for WebSphere, using a "V5 default messaging provider" and a Websphere6.1

I now try to access it using a standalone app (JUnit Test), in order to put some messages in it. I currently use the following code:

```
        Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "corbaloc::localhost:2809"); 
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);

        javax.jms.Queue queue = (javax.jms.Queue) ctx.lookup("Topic");
```

On the last line I get the following exception:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: The JNDI operation "lookupExt"on the context "vwagwolot0awNode01Cell/nodes/vwagwolot0awNode01/servers/server1" with the name "Topic" failed.  Please get the root cause Throwable contained in this NamingException for more information.  Root exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent: method isAnyTracingEnabled()Z not found
    at com.ibm.websphere.pmi.reqmetrics.PmiReqMetrics.register(PmiReqMetrics.java:949)
    at com.ibm.websphere.pmi.reqmetrics.PmiReqMetrics.<clinit>(PmiReqMetrics.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1505)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:1358)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:172)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:361)
    at de.volkswagen.oracle.provisioning.util.test.QueueTest.testQueue(QueueTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
root cause:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent: method isAnyTracingEnabled()Z not found
    at com.ibm.websphere.pmi.reqmetrics.PmiReqMetrics.register(PmiReqMetrics.java:949)
    at com.ibm.websphere.pmi.reqmetrics.PmiReqMetrics.<clinit>(PmiReqMetrics.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookupExt(CNContextImpl.java:1505)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.jndicos.CNContextImpl.lookup(CNContextImpl.java:1358)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:172)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:361)
    at <package name here>.QueueTest.testQueue(QueueTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:391)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Any hints, what I can do in order to fix it?
In order to get that far, I added the ws_runtime.jar into the classpath, which I found somewhere in the RAD installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check which JARs you have on the classpath.  A cursory glance is indicating a mismatch somewhere.  This line:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.ejs.ras.TraceComponent: method isAnyTracingEnabled()Z not found
```

Is telling you that the `com.ibm.websphere.pmi.reqmetrics.PmiReqMetrics.register` method is trying to call the `isAnyTracingElementEnabled` method on `TraceComponent`, but `TraceComponent` doesn't have that method.  I'm guessing that the JAR that has `TraceComponent` in is the wrong one.

Comment: I agree. And I would think it is ws_runtime.jar although, now that I am writing this I guess I should check that. But question is: where do I get the correct version?

Comment: Can't help you there, I don't use the app in question

Comment: two problems needed solving: I had the Testcode in the same project as the EJB to be tested. This caused the described problem, because with the EJB came many classpath entries I didn't want for the test. For the correct Library the RAD offers a server runtime library, which we added to the buildpath, which at least solved this problem